# Why does a nested struct edited in a func called in a goroutine seems to change after append to a slice?

Tags: go

I need explanation about modifying nested struct from a method of the parents struct.

I test these 2 go playground:
In this one https://goplay.tools/snippet/ibxrvhIRYte

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

const (
    gr = 5
)

type Child struct {
    Grid  int
    Child string
}

type Parent struct {
    Childs []Child
    Parent string
}

func (parent Parent) ChangeChild(gr int) Parent {
    for i, _ := range parent.Childs {
        parent.Childs[i].Grid = gr + i
    }
    return parent
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var s []Parent
    var childs []Child
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        childs = append(childs, Child{Child: "child"})
    }
    wg.Add(gr)
    for i := 0; i < gr; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer mu.Unlock()
            defer wg.Done()
            parent := Parent{Childs: childs, Parent: " parent"}
            parent = parent.ChangeChild(i)
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Println(parent)
            s = append(s, parent)
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

The line 45 print the result slice. But it looks like each on the element of the slice are the same.

In this one https://goplay.tools/snippet/T4BGeDqfJAi

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

const (
    gr = 5
)

type Child struct {
    Grid  int
    Child string
}

type Parent struct {
    Childs []Child
    Parent string
}

func (parent Parent) ChangeChild(gr int) Parent {
    for i, _ := range parent.Childs {
        parent.Childs[i].Grid = gr + i
    }
    return parent
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var s []Parent
    wg.Add(gr)
    for i := 0; i < gr; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer mu.Unlock()
            defer wg.Done()
            var childs []Child
            for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
                childs = append(childs, Child{Child: "child"})
            }
            parent := Parent{Childs: childs, Parent: " parent"}
            parent = parent.ChangeChild(i)
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Println(parent)
            s = append(s, parent)
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

The slice looks better.

The only diff is this piece of code :

```
var childs []Child
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    childs = append(childs, Child{Child: "child"})
}
```

is outside the goroutine in the 1st playground, and inside the goroutine in the 2nd one.

Why, moving these lines change the result?

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: Just added the code of the 2 snippets as requested

Comment: Your first example has a [data race](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector); however I suspect your main issue is a misunderstanding of [Slice internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro#slice-internals); [this example](https://goplay.tools/snippet/aN1TPg3UgE3) might help.

Comment: In the first snippet you are creating 5 instances of parent sharing the same childs slice. In the second snippet each has a difference slice. You say that the second one is "better" but "better" depends on what you are trying to achieve.